# DiscountManager class in C#

Tags: c#, formatting

I built a class in C#, `DiscountManager`, which is responsible for calculating a customer discount based on years of loyalty. I want to refactor it and am seeking any suggestions for conciseness and efficiency.

```
public class DiscountManager
{
  public decimal Calculate(decimal amount, int type, int years)
  {
    decimal result = 0;
    decimal disc = (years > 5) ? (decimal)5/100 : (decimal)years/100; 
    if (type == 1)
    {
      result = amount;
    }
    else if (type == 2)
    {
      result = (amount - (0.1m * amount)) - disc * (amount - (0.1m * amount));
    }
    else if (type == 3)
    {
      result = (0.7m * amount) - disc * (0.7m * amount);
    }
    else if (type == 4)
    {
      result = (amount - (0.5m * amount)) - disc * (amount - (0.5m * amount));
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend to move `discountForLoyaltyInPercentage` and `switch` statement into their own methods.

The issue with the current method is that it has multiple purposes :

1. Calculating and setting the Loyalty Discount Percentage.
2. Calculating and setting the General Discount Percentage.
3. Applying All discounts to the price, and return the result.

If you move each point above to one method, it would be easier to read, extend, and to have a proper handling.

```
public static class DiscountManager
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates and returns the discount percentage 
    /// based on the time period of the account (number of years since created).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="timeOfHavingAccountInYears"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static decimal GetLoyaltyDiscountPercentage(int timeOfHavingAccountInYears)
    {
        return timeOfHavingAccountInYears > 5 ? 0.50m : timeOfHavingAccountInYears / 100.00m;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates and returns the general discount 
    /// based on the <see cref="AccountStatus"/> 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="accountStatus"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static decimal GetDiscountPercentage(AccountStatus accountStatus)
    {
        switch(accountStatus)
        {
            case AccountStatus.SimpleCustomer:
                return 0.10m;
            case AccountStatus.ValuableCustomer:
                return 0.30m;
            case AccountStatus.MostValuableCustomer:
                return 0.50m;
            default:
                return 0.00m;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Applying the discounts (if any) on the price and returns the final price (after discounts).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="price"></param>
    /// <param name="accountStatus"></param>
    /// <param name="timeOfHavingAccountInYears"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static decimal ApplyDiscount(decimal price , AccountStatus accountStatus , int timeOfHavingAccountInYears)
    {
        decimal loyaltyDiscountPercentage = GetLoyaltyDiscountPercentage(timeOfHavingAccountInYears);

        decimal discountPercentage = GetDiscountPercentage(accountStatus);

        decimal priceAfterDiscount = price * (1.00m - discountPercentage);
        
        decimal finalPrice = priceAfterDiscount - ( loyaltyDiscountPercentage * priceAfterDiscount );
        
        return finalPrice;
    }   
}
```

since all methods don't need several instance, and the nature of the class is unchangeable,  making the class `static` would be more appropriate.

You can then reuse it :

```
var finalPrice = DiscountManager.ApplyDiscount(price, accountStatus, timeOfHavingAccountInYears);
```

Now, this would be fine for small discount system, but with larger scale  discount system, you may need to use abstractions to make each discount with its own properties. (so you can manage discounts on accounts, products, season discounts .. etc).

Something like this :

```
public abstract class AccountDiscount
{
    public abstract decimal Discount { get; }
    
    public virtual decimal GetDiscountedPrice(decimal price)
    {
        return price * (1.00m - Discount);
    }

}

public class DefaultDiscount : AccountDiscount
{
    public override decimal Discount => 0.00m;
}


public class SimpleCustomerDiscount : AccountDiscount
{
    public override decimal Discount => 0.10m;
}

public class LoyaltyDiscount : AccountDiscount
{
    public override decimal Discount { get; }

    public LoyaltyDiscount(int totalYears) : base()
    {
        Discount = totalYears > 5 ? 0.50m : totalYears / 100.00m;
    }
}
```

then you can add each discount to an account and store that in the database level, which will help you achieve this :

```
public decimal ApplyDiscounts(IEnumerable<AccountDiscount> discounts, decimal price)
{
    decimal finalPrice = price;
    
    foreach(var discount in discounts)
    {
        finalPrice -= discount.GetDiscountedPrice(finalPrice);
    }
    
    return finalPrice;
}

public decimal  ApplyDiscountsByAccountId(int accountId, decimal price)
{
    List<AccountDiscount> discounts = _someRepoistory.GetAccountDiscounts(accountId);
    
    return ApplyDiscounts(discounts, price);    
}
```

as here the `discounts` would be already linked to an account, and you only need to handle the logic between them, so you can pass an `accountId` and the system will populate the account profile along with its registered discounts. This is just an example on how it can be implemented on a larger scale.

Comment: I like the way you split it into functions, but be mindful to not confuse percentages and factors. In `GetDiscountPercentage` it looks like `SimpleCustomer` will get a 90% discount.

Comment: @JohanduToit my apology on my humble understanding on math, I did it because I was wondering why the `ValuableCustomer` has a higher discount than `MostValuableCustomer` ? so I figured, they must use `price * (100 - (actual discount * 100) / 100)`, so doing `price * .9` or `price * 0.7` would return the price after the discount.

Comment: No need for apologies =) You could change it to something like this [TIO](https://tio.run/##jZExa8NADIX3@xUa7YKDQ@kS0yGk0KkQCGRXZbk5uPOZk64ZSn67Yzc4JClt@jbpPX3DE0nhQxsK2bFzfd9F@4nKIIpqCWom69HBK@uLFQqp1TVH4lbxg7MlfW82QzYJ4OWUmy8Dg2RvlXbZjTc6J38UoTBcsWYb6zvHqyQaPMfFOToqsqbYQjmbl776C7JFl/D9LubxDuYtiP4T9XSJqrnB5PSXaDlFD@ZgzNTzUD/xslGOU93wfFrCA2Tz8QoKqH@8Iq/6/gg)

Comment: @JohanduToit isn't `price * (1.00m - discountPercentage)` is the same as `price * 0.9` ? could you please enlighten me with the differences ? because both approaches will return the same results ?

Comment: You are correct, but if you look at `GetDiscountPercentage` on its own, it makes more sense to return actual percentages rather than factors.

Comment: @JohanduToit i've got your point, and you're correct, looking at it, it seems it would be better if returns the percentage. thanks man for your eagle eye ;).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130129/discussion-between-johan-du-toit-and-isr5).

Answer (score 4):

Try to keep your calculations consistent.

```cs
price * 0.9m
```

Is the same as

```cs
(price - (0.1m * price))
```

Based on this you could have simplified it to the following:

```cs
public decimal ApplyDiscount(decimal price, AccountStatus accountStatus, int timeOfHavingAccountInYears)
{
    bool registered;
    decimal baseFactor;
    switch (accountStatus)
    {
        case AccountStatus.NotRegistered:
            registered = false;
            baseFactor = 1.0m;
            break;
        case AccountStatus.SimpleCustomer:
            registered = true;
            baseFactor = 0.9m;
            break;
        case AccountStatus.ValuableCustomer:
            registered = true;
            baseFactor = 0.7m;
            break;
        case AccountStatus.MostValuableCustomer:
            registered = true;
            baseFactor = 0.5m;
            break;
        default:
            throw new Exception("Invalid status: " + accountStatus);
    }

    // apply base discount
    price *= baseFactor;

    // apply loyalty discount
    if (registered == true)
    {
        int years = Math.Min(5, timeOfHavingAccountInYears);
        decimal loyaltyFactor = 1.0m - (decimal)years / 100m;
        price *= loyaltyFactor;
    }

    return price;
}
```

You can also use a `Dictionary` like this:

```cs
class StatusValues
{
    public bool registered;
    public decimal baseFactor;
}

public class DiscountManager
{
    public decimal ApplyDiscount(decimal price, AccountStatus accountStatus, int timeOfHavingAccountInYears)
    {
        var statusTypes = new Dictionary<AccountStatus, StatusValues>()
        {
            { AccountStatus.NotRegistered, new StatusValues{ registered = false, baseFactor = 1.0m } },
            { AccountStatus.SimpleCustomer, new StatusValues{ registered = true, baseFactor = 0.9m } },
            { AccountStatus.ValuableCustomer, new StatusValues{ registered = true, baseFactor = 0.7m } }, 
            { AccountStatus.MostValuableCustomer, new StatusValues { registered = true, baseFactor = 0.5m } }
        };
        var statusType = statusTypes[accountStatus];
        // apply base discount
        price *= statusType.baseFactor;
        // apply loyalty discount
        if (statusType.registered)
        {
            int years = Math.Min(5, timeOfHavingAccountInYears);
            decimal loyaltyFactor = 1.0m - (decimal)years / 100m;
            price *= loyaltyFactor;
        }
        return price;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using extension methods to enhance the `AccountStatus` providing the required values such as `registered`. Also consider extracting the calculation of the loyalty factor to a separate method with `timeOfHaving...` as a parameter.